# Is there an equivalent for SCNAction, SCNTransaction or SKAction in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scenekit

Hopefully this is a quick question. I have been developing with SpriteKit and SceneKit for a year now. I find the frameworks really intuitive.

Does Anyone know if there is an equivalent in Unity for the SCNAction SCNTransaction or SKAction in Unity apart from just manually coding in these Animations? Those for me are very easy to use, sort of like a black box version of an animation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is nothing built in Unity that ressembles SCNActions.

However, I have heard a lot about the plugin [iTween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/index.php). Looking at the documentation it seems to be pretty close from what you're looking for. I never used it, so be sure to check if it fits your needs and/or if any other alternative exist.

Else, you can simply create them from scratch. It requires a little bit of code but it's overall pretty easy. You most of the times only need to interpolate between two values at every frame, from the starting time to the end of the duration.